# How to get boost::asio::acceptor to accept connections again after closing it?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

My server wants to limit the number of concurrently established sessions (TCP sockets).
When the max. number of sessions/connections is reached, then I just `close()` the acceptor.
When other sessions get closed, then I thought to just `open()` the acceptor again.

Creating the acceptor via constructor, giving endpoint, protocol and port as part of my class member init-list:

```
, mEndPoint( boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), port )
, mAcceptor( io_context, mEndPoint )
```

And then, later:

```
mAcceptor.async_accept(
                          [this]( boost::system::error_code ec, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket )
                          {... }
                       );
```

Sessions can be established successfully.
When reaching the max. number of sessions, I just close the acceptor via `mAcceptor.close();` (in the completion handler) - and new clients cannot establish a connection, as expected (getting a "Connection refused" error).

Now when calling `mAcceptor.open( mEndPoint.protocol() );` and calling the same `mAcceptor.async_accept(...)` then immediately an exception `system:22` gets thrown.

What is missing?

I tried calling `mAcceptor.bind( endpoint );`, which results in the exception `address already in use`.

I tried `mAcceptor.wait( boost::asio::socket_base::wait_type::wait_read );`, which doesn't make a difference.

The same when calling `mAcceptor.listen();` - when a new client tries to establish a connection it gets "Connection refused" - and on the server-side the async lambda isn't called.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start listening on the acceptor.

> I tried calling mAcceptor.bind( endpoint );, which results in the exception address already in use.

Then use the SO_REUSEADDR option.

Here's a simple, self-contained example:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std::literals;
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using asio::ip::tcp;

void accept_n(tcp::acceptor& acc, unsigned n, std::string const& identification) {
    for (std::string msg; n--; msg.clear()) {
        auto conn = acc.accept();
        auto len  = read_until(conn, asio::dynamic_buffer(msg), "\n");
        std::cout << identification << " accepted #" << n           //
                  << " (msg: " << quoted(msg.substr(0, len)) << ")" //
                  << " from " << conn.remote_endpoint() << std::endl;
        write(conn, asio::buffer(identification + "\n"));
    }
}

int main() {
    asio::io_context ioc;
    tcp::endpoint const listen_ep{{}, 8989};
    tcp::acceptor acc(ioc, listen_ep);
    acc.set_option(tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));

    accept_n(acc, 5, "first");

    std::cout << " === closing " << std::endl;
    acc.close();

    std::cout << " === re-opening " << std::endl;
    acc.open(tcp::v4());
    acc.set_option(tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));
    acc.bind(listen_ep);
    acc.listen();

    accept_n(acc, 5, "second");
    
    std::cout << " === done " << std::endl;
}
```

Live demo: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c95e6a39788dfb9)**

[image]

### Don't Repeat Yourself

In the interest of clean code, you can make both accepts identical by not using the shorthand construction:

```
int main() {
    asio::io_context ioc;
    tcp::endpoint const listen_ep{{}, 8989};
    tcp::acceptor acc(ioc /*, listen_ep*/); // no listen here

    for (std::string const identification : {"first", "second", "third"}) {
        if (acc.is_open()) {
            std::cout << " === closing " << std::endl;
            acc.close();
        }

        std::cout << " === (re-)opening " << std::endl;
        acc.open(tcp::v4());
        acc.set_option(tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));
        acc.bind(listen_ep);
        acc.listen();

        accept_n(acc, 5, "second");
    }
}
```

Of course, this just begs the question, why re-use the acceptor at all. In practice you would simply encapsulate everything:

```
struct Service {
    asio::io_context    ioc_;
    tcp::endpoint const ep_{{}, 8989};
    tcp::acceptor       acc_{ioc_};

    void accept_n(unsigned n, std::string const& identification) {
        if (acc_.is_open()) {
            std::cout << " === closing " << std::endl;
            acc_.close();
        }

        std::cout << " === (re-)opening " << std::endl;
        acc_.open(tcp::v4());
        acc_.set_option(tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));
        acc_.bind(ep_);
        acc_.listen();

        for (std::string msg; n--; msg.clear()) {
            auto conn = acc_.accept();
            auto len  = read_until(conn, asio::dynamic_buffer(msg), "\n");
            std::cout << identification << " accepted #" << n               //
                      << " (msg: " << quoted(msg.substr(0, len - 1)) << ")" //
                      << " from " << conn.remote_endpoint() << std::endl;
            write(conn, asio::buffer(identification + "\n"));
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    for (std::string const identification : {"first", "second", "third"})
        Service().accept_n(5, identification);
}
```

And I can't think of any reason why

```
int main() {
    Service svc;
    for (std::string const identification : {"first", "second", "third"})
        svc.accept_n(5, identification);
}
```

would be objectively better/more useful.

### Not Closing Is Simpler

You may not even need to close the acceptor:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b03aa7f9dea99f9f)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using asio::ip::tcp;

struct Service {
    asio::io_context    ioc_;
    tcp::endpoint const ep_{{}, 8989};
    tcp::acceptor       acc_{ioc_, ep_};

    void accept_n(unsigned n, std::string const& identification) {
        for (std::string msg; n--; msg.clear()) {
            auto conn = acc_.accept();
            auto len  = read_until(conn, asio::dynamic_buffer(msg), "\n");
            std::cout << identification << " accepted #" << n               //
                      << " (msg: " << quoted(msg.substr(0, len - 1)) << ")" //
                      << " from " << conn.remote_endpoint() << std::endl;
            write(conn, asio::buffer(identification + "\n"));
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    Service svc;
    for (std::string const identification : {"first", "second", "third"})
        svc.accept_n(5, identification);
}
```

And live:

[image]