# Bind boost::asio socket to new port

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-asio

I haven’t yet successfully found a way to change the port of a boost asio udp socket at run time, after the initialization. Is this possible or would I have to close the socket and re-open with a completely new socket? Thanks in  advance.

For some background, I initialized the socket using socket(io_service, udp::endpoint(udp::v4, port)) and then use an async_receive_from() function to receive the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should technically close and reopen. Your original code

```
socket s(ioc, udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), port));
```

is roughly equivalent to

```
socket s(ioc);
s.open(udp::v4());
s.bind(udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), port));
```

So, what you could do is

```
s.close();
s.open(udp::v4());
s.bind(udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), other_port));
```

> As far as I remember some calls are documented to automatically close/re-open the socket if needed, but I'd rather be explicit.

#### Note

I'd venture that it is rarely a useful idea to re-use an IO object when the native handle isn't. See this very similar question: [How to get boost::asio::acceptor to accept connections again after closing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75827861/how-to-get-boostasioacceptor-to-accept-connections-again-after-closing-it/75828304#75828304)

In the end it's probably easier to "just" replace the entire `s` instance than to manage its state manually.

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful. If I may ask, why is it rarely a useful idea to re-use an IO object? If I close and reopen/bind it, I don't see how it's any different than created a new one.

Comment: Isn't that the point? Why would you take pains to know how to close, open, bind, listen on an acceptor when you can just do `acceptor_ = tcp::acceptor(ex, {{}, 8989}});` and have a new listening socket bound to localhost:8989 already opened? So, it isn't any different, but it *is* much simpler.